# C# XML deserialize self closing raw element

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I need to process some XML input which has HTML code in some tags. For these tags I want the raw content to process it later. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11235379) and used `XmlElement` which works fine in most cases. The only problem I'm facing are self closing tags.

```cs
[Serializable]
public class Root
{
    public XmlElement Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));

var obj1 = serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(@"<Root><Description><p>test</p></Description><Name>Test</Name></Root>"));
// Description: "Element, Name=\"p\""
// Name: "Test"

var obj2 = serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(@"<Root><Description></Description><Name>Test</Name></Root>"));
// Description: null
// Name: "Test"

var obj3 = serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(@"<Root><Description/><Name>Test</Name></Root>"));
// Description: "Element, Name=\"Name\""
// Name: null
```

`obj1` and `obj2` are ok (`obj2.Description == ""` would be better) but in `obj3` the `Description` member is greedy and contains the `Name` part.

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Try adding the [XmlElement] attribute to the Name property.

Comment: @RonBeyer no need, that is implied

Comment: I genuinely didn't expect this to repro, but it does; so ... yeah, looks like a bug in XmlSerializer, and would need to be fixed there!

Comment: Thank you, I opened an issue https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/80699

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround is to declare a custom class for the `Description` property, matching any content inside the element using the [[XmlAnyElement] attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute?view=net-7.0):

```
public class Root
{
    public Description Description { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Description
{
    [XmlAnyElement]
    public List<XmlElement> Content { get; set; }
}
```

The only drawback is this won't work for mixed content. In other words, this will deserialize well:

```
<Description><p>test</p></Description>
```

but this won't, deserializing the `<span>` only:

```
<Description>some <span>other</span> text</Description>
```

Should you need mixed content, implement `IXmlSerializable` on the `Description` class.

However, it does work for `<Description/>`. That being said, I do agree with @MarcGravell that it's a bug in `XmlSerializer` and shall be reported.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested I [reported this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/80699).

I use this code now to workaround the issue:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Schema;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));

        var obj1 = serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(@"<Root><Description><p>test</p></Description><Name>Test</Name></Root>"));
        Console.WriteLine(obj1); // Description: <p>test</p> / Name: Test

        var obj2 = serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(@"<Root><Description></Description><Name>Test</Name></Root>"));
        Console.WriteLine(obj2); // Description:  / Name: Test

        var obj3 = serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(@"<Root><Description/><Name>Test</Name></Root>"));
        Console.WriteLine(obj3); // Description:  / Name: Test
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public HtmlElement Description { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public override string ToString() => $"Description: {Description.Content} / Name: {Name}";
    }
    
    public class HtmlElement : IXmlSerializable
    {
        public string Content { get; set; } = "";

        public XmlSchema GetSchema() => null;

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            reader.MoveToContent();

            if (!reader.IsEmptyElement && reader is XmlTextReader xtr)
            {
                Content = xtr.ReadInnerXml();
            }
        }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```